# USSD response in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, ussd

I am working on a SMS application in which when I send an sms from device in debug mode on anther number, I recieve notification of my deducted balance through USSD on device. That USSD message get printed on my console window.
I can see these USSD messages on my console but getting nothing to fetch them as a response in control.
on console it is shows like this.
**Phone USSD Data:**

Please suggest me how this is possible to get the USSD response as that is printed on my console than there must be a way to get that response.